# The authentication doc gives a wrong domain for authentication

Tags: bug, api-v2.2, documentation, authentication

The [authentication doc page](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/authentication) now lists URL's like:

- `https://stackoverflow.com/oauth`
- `https://stackoverflow.com/oauth/access_token`
- etc.

While these seem to work, the correct domain is `stackexchange.com`, as previously listed in the doc page (and still works).

**The API is network-wide, not limited to Stack Overflow.**

The doc page seems to have been silently reverted to `stackoverflow.com` around *April Fool's day* of last year.  ([March 14, 2018](https://web.archive.org/web/20180314124449/http://api.stackexchange.com/docs/authentication) was still good, but the page had been regressed by [April 14, 2018](https://web.archive.org/web/20180414190213/http://api.stackexchange.com/docs/authentication).)

Comment: +1 It also seems like the oauth dialog page now has only SO branding, the main Stack Exchange logo would probably be more appropriate! (I guess it's SO's logo because either URL redirects to stackoverflow.com to complete the process?)

Comment: @ᔕᖺᘎᕊ Yes, and [it gets worse](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/325629/users-are-able-to-register-apps-that-look-official-for-phishing).